# Como puedo lograr que mi .apk no sea compartida para multiples dispositivos?

Tags: java, android, apk

Estoy utilizando android studio, lo que quiero lograr es vender mi .apk sin utilizar AppStore.
Estoy tratando de pensar alguna idea para que mi app, mas bien el .apk, no sea compartido por varias personas que puedan comprar mi producto por unica vez y repartirlo entre multiples usuarios.

Una manera que se me ocurrió es utilizar logos y marcas de agua ya que se trata de una aplicacion para medicos.

Pensaba en otra opcion involucrando una base de datos local, pero al borrar la caché de la app la base de datos vuelve a ser la que originalmente se encuentra en los asserts de la app. Por lo tanto reiniciaría el sistema si quisiese.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: El esquema típico de validación de licencias es por medio de un servidor que autentica la misma. Es igual para aplicaciones de escritorio y móviles.

Comment: Exacto, aunque debí agregar que estoy buscando alguna solucion local.

Comment: Genera licencias basadas en la MAC address del dispositivo.

Comment: ¿Es la copia realmente un problema? Vas a gastar tiempo y esfuerzo en una funcionalidad que probablemente no te rente un peso más.

Comment: @LuchoQuiru es incorrecto usar la MAC address ya que el valor que se obtiene actualmente no es unico entre dispositivos.

Answer (score 2):

Como ha comentado @PepeNO, una posible solución, sería con la MAC del dispositivo, que es única. Podrías obtenerla mediante código y enviarla a una base de datos, limitando las licencias de uso a terminales cuya MAC está en tu base de datos.

Hace tiempo la dirección MAC se obtenía de forma sencilla, pero tras la versión 6, se limitó el acceso por seguridad, sin embargo con éste código si funcionaba.

Te la dejo por si como digo aún funciona.

Ojo, tienes que probarla en un dispositivo físico, no sirve en el emulador.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    //un textview que recoge el texto del método
    txtMAC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMAC);
    //un botón que ejecuta el método
    btnMAC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMAC);

    //el botón
    btnMAC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //llamamos al método para obtener la MAC y recibimos el resultado en un string
            String MAC = getMacAddress();

            //Si el string está vacío
            if (MAC.isEmpty()){
                //escribimos el aviso en el textview
                txtMAC.setText("Error en la obtención de la MAC");
            }
            else{
                //si tiene algún dato, esperemos que sea la MAC y la vemos
                txtMAC.setText("La MAC es " + MAC);
            }
        }
    });

}
//el método que obtiene la MAC
public static String getMacAddress() {
    try {

        List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface nif : all) {
            if (!nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) continue;

            byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
            if (macBytes == null) {
                return "";
            }

            StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b : macBytes) {
                res1.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF) + ":");
            }

            if (res1.length() > 0) {
                res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
            }
            return res1.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Error", ex.getMessage());
    }
    return "";
}
```

El método lo obtuve hace tiempo buscando por internet, espero te pueda servir

Comment: Esto NO es posible " una posible solución, sería con la MAC del dispositivo, que es única" , se puede obtener la MAC pero demasiados dispositivos arrojarian el mismo valor.

Comment: La dirección MAC (siglas en inglés de Media Access Control) es un identificador de 48 bits (6 bloques de dos caracteres hexadecimales [8 bits]) que corresponde de forma única a una tarjeta o dispositivo de red. En los móviles Android, todos los tipos de conexión tienen su propio identificador. El módem para la conexión de datos tiene un IMEI único, mientras que la conexión Wi-Fi y Bluetooth tienen una dirección MAC. Aunque si es cierto que se puede trastear y cambiar, generalmente no es algo que sepa o conozcan los usuarios y nunca se cambian, por lo que siempre seguiran siendo únicas

Comment: has probado que valor se obtiene como MAcAddress para tu dispositivo?

Comment: Si no me equivoco, los métodos WifiInfo.getMacAddress() y BluetoothAdapter.getAddress() retornan una MAC errónea 02:00:00:00:00:00 desde la versión 6.0 de android por motivos de seguridad. Pero el método que puse en mi respuesta se estuvo usando para autentificación de terminales en active directory con versiones posteriores en una aplicación de mi anterior empresa. Aunque como pongo en la respuesta, es algo que llevo tiempo sin usar y que hoy en día desconozco si puede seguir funcionando.

Comment: Pues no funciona actualmente, y si el usuario además usara sus datos móvil pues tampoco funcionaría.